# Bulk changing symbology using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, arcgis-pro

I'm currently processing a land classification map which is in feature class format. This map is symbolised by a defined color for each land class (yellow for sand, green for vegetation and blue for water).

Every time I conduct a process, I need to re-assign the symbology to the output.

Is there anyway I can re-apply the same colors from one feature class to another without having to manually selecting each colour one-by-one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Apply Symbology From Layer (Data Management)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/apply-symbology-from-layer.htm) tool:

> Applies the symbology from a layer or layer file to the input. It can be applied to feature, raster, network analysis, TIN, and geostatistical layers.
>
> [image: Blockquote]

To do a bulk update, you can use the standard ArcGIS Pro batch functionality - right click the tool and select "Batch".